# Trying to run a program from github which I've installed using pip3. But when I try to run in through the Mac OS terminal, it require's "Python 3.6+"

Tags: python

Just new to everything coding, but I need to run a github program called  ["Twint"](https://github.com/twintproject/twint)

I've already installed all the requirements, even the latest Python but it still says

**"[-] TWINT requires Python version 3.6+."**. Now upon some research, I shouldn't replace the default Python 2.7 with a new one to avoid messing up the system, but how am I going to run this program?

[Screenshot of MAC OS Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXFUk.png)

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Just new to everything coding" Then you should study how to write code before trying to use third-party libraries. If you just want to run someone else's program, then you don't have a programming question, you have a tech support question; you should ask the authors, not us. You have installed an appropriate version of Python, but this program is apparently not *aware of* it. You will need to do something program-specific to fix that.

Comment: There are tons of tutorials and guides online for how to install python3 alongside the default python 2.7 installation on mac OS. [this article](https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/osx/) for instance. Can you clarify what you need help with exactly, and why such online guides did not help you?

Comment: As a side note, [please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: macOS has shipped a version of Python 3 for some time. You just have to run `python3` instead of `python`. Your issue is how probably with `twint` was installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [repository](https://github.com/twintproject/twint) in the question and upon reading the [**Installing** section of the Readme](https://github.com/twintproject/twint#installing),you have to do the following to
install the tool :

Navigate to the source code directory in the terminal (which you're already in , after looking at the screenshot) and then run the following code in the terminal :

```
pip3 install twint
```

**Side-Note:**

pip3 -- pip3 is an updated version of pip which is used basically for python 3+.

You already have the latest version of python3 (as seen from the screenshot),so this should work.

You don't need to do anything else other than look into the [Readme/Documentaion of the tool](https://github.com/twintproject/twint#twint---twitter-intelligence-tool) on how to use the tool

Comment: it worked! extremely grateful, thanks so much!

Comment: That's great !! Could you please accept my answer like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow) if it's the correct one

Comment: got it! thank you so much